# Lookup in loop using xslt 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I need to do a lookup in a recursive loop. For example below is a xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AggregatedData>
       <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
          <wd:Report_Entry>
             <wd:num>1</wd:num>
          </wd:Report_Entry>
          <wd:Report_Entry>
             <wd:num>2</wd:num>
          </wd:Report_Entry>
          <wd:Report_Entry>
             <wd:num>4</wd:num>
          </wd:Report_Entry>
          <wd:Report_Entry>
             <wd:num>5</wd:num>
          </wd:Report_Entry>
       </wd:Report_Data>
     
       <root>
          <row>
             <my_num>6</my_num>    --->> Can be any number
          </row>
       </root>
    </AggregatedData>
```

Now, I need to lookup my_num in Report_Data if available. If found then I need to subtract 1 from my_num and then lookup again until "not found"

For example, if my_num is 6, I need to subtract 1 from 6 (which is 5) and then lookup if 5 is found in the report_Data. If found, Need to subtract 1 from 5 now (which is 4) and then again lookup 4 in the report_data. Keep iterating this loop until "not found"

***Expected output*:
Not found: 3**

Below is a xslt I was able to prepare so far but facing error xsl:template must be at top level, but I am not able to reframe the xslt:

```
        <xsl:template match="AggregatedData">
            <FinalData>
                <xsl:iterate select="*">
                    <xsl:param name="numMap" as="map(xs:integer,element(wd:Report_Entry))" select="map{}"/>
                    
                    <xsl:choose>
                        
                        <xsl:when test="self::wd:Report_Data">
                            <xsl:next-iteration>
                                <xsl:with-param name="numMap"
                                    select="fold-left(
                                    wd:Report_Entry/copy-of(),
                                    map{},
                                    function($map,$entry) {
                                    let $key:=xs:integer($entry/wd:num) return
                                    if ($key)
                                    then map:put($map,$key,$entry)
                                    else
                                    $map})"
                                />  
                            </xsl:next-iteration>
                        </xsl:when>                  
                        
                        
                        <xsl:when test="self::root">
    
                            <xsl:for-each select="row/copy-of()">
                                <rows>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                                    
                                    <splitExistFlag>

                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                            <xsl:when test="exists($numMap(current()/xs:integer(my_num - 1))/wd:num)">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'found'"/> 

                                          ------<< Need a recursive loop here after further subtracting 1 from my_num >>------

                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'Not found'"/>                                            
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                            </splitExistFlag>                                

                        </rows>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </FinalData>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Please help!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve and how you expect anyone to tell from an incomplete snippet   (with a start tag for `xsl:iterate` but no end tag ) to fix that code. Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not clear why you put a template into some nested code, in any version of XSLT an XSLT xsl:template, whether named or matching or both, has to be a top-level child of the `xsl:stylesheet` (or `xsl:transform`) root element of the XSLT module. Anyway, why do you need the `xsl:iterate`, why can't you simply navigate the tree? Is that an attempt to work with XSLT 3 and streaming?

Comment: For example, if my_num is 6, I need to subtract 1 from 6 (which is 5) and then lookup if 5 is found in the report_Data. If found, Need to subtract 1 from 5 now (which is 4) and then again lookup 4 in the report_data. Keep iterating this loop until "not found"

Comment: I don't see why a recursive function or fold-left or xsl:iterate can't be used, where did you get the idea to throw in a named template in the middle of the code and in XSLT 3 where functions are much more compact than named templates? And the whole code looks rather convoluted unless some parts are written that way to have a streaming solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output. Maybe (!) then we'll understand what is the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: The example is confusing. You say *"I need to lookup my_num in Report_Data if available. If found then I need to subtract 1 from my_num..."* - but it is NOT found.

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking far too procedurally:

> For example, if my_num is 6, I need to subtract 1 from 6 (which is 5)
> and then lookup if 5 is found in the report_Data. If found, Need to
> subtract 1 from 5 now (which is 4) and then again lookup 4 in the
> report_data. Keep iterating this loop until "not found"

Try to express it more declaratively, and you'll find it's easier to write the code.

As far as I can see, you want the highest integer less than `my_num` that is not present in `report_Data`. That is, you want

```
max((1 to my_num - 1)[not(. = //wd:num)])
```

or if the numbers are much larger, it might be a microsecond or two faster to do:

```
reverse(1 to my_num - 1)[not(. = //wd:num)][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not follow the logic of your example. Here is something simple that you might be able to adapt:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entry" match="wd:Report_Entry" use="wd:num" />

<xsl:template match="/AggregatedData">
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="wd:Report_Data" />
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/row">
            <row start="{my_num}">
                <xsl:for-each select="reverse(1 to my_num)">
                    <result n="{.}">
                        <xsl:if test="not(key('entry', string(.), $data))">Not </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:text>found</xsl:text>
                    </result>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your (updated) example input, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <row start="6">
      <result n="6">Not found</result>
      <result n="5">found</result>
      <result n="4">found</result>
      <result n="3">Not found</result>
      <result n="2">found</result>
      <result n="1">found</result>
   </row>
</results>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MXNWN3/1

Comment: Thanks. This is very close. I want to start the loop from (my_num - 1) and stop as soon as I hit "Not found"

Comment: How important is it to exit when not found? You could simply test them all and return the first one that's false.